# How to remove the watermark in the rendered image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I used Blender cycles to render an image, but the output has a watermark with some words in the top left hand corner.

How can I make it disappear by changing the related setting?

[image: Blender 2.73a - Cycles (newline) Date 2016/05/09 15:43:59 (newline) RenderTime 49:45.57]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the properties window, open **Render** tab, scroll down to **Metadata** section and disable **Stamp Output.**

[image]

Comment: @Peng  If this answer has satisfactorily answered your question you can mark it as accepted with the checkmark under the voting buttons.